# Checkboxes in MVC not functioning correctly

Tags: html, forms, model-view-controller

Ok, I posted a question on stackoverflow regarding checkboxes that had a nullable view model parameter and was told this wouldn't work. I've substantially reworked my application to support a non-nullable view model parameter so I'm ready to ask my question again.

I have a checkbox in my application, like this:

```
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.IsNonUk)
```

which renders in the browser like this:

```
    <input data-val="true" id="IsNonUk" name="IsNonUk" type="checkbox" value="true" />
    <input name="IsNonUk" type="hidden" value="false" />
```

Inspecting the element in Chrome reveals this markup:

```
    <input data-val="true" id="IsNonUk" name="IsNonUk" type="checkbox" value="">
    <input name="IsNonUk" type="hidden" value="">
```

My action has this signature:

```
    public ActionResult CreateSelfPay(CreateSelfPayViewModel viewModel)
```

and my CreateSelfPayViewModel view model contains this property:

```
    public class CreateSelfPayViewModel : ViewModel
    {
        // ..
        [DisplayName("Is non-UK")]
        public bool IsNonUk { get; set; }
        // ..
    }
```

The problem is that no matter what I do to the checkbox the values posted back to the server are both null which results in a false value in the view model. I have checked this with Fiddler.

What is going on? Why can't I get a true value if the box is checked?

I hope someone can help!

== More information ==

The application is using various libraries such as jQuery, jQuery validate, jQuery UI and Bootstrap. Perhaps one of these is fiddling with the input values since they are null when inspected with the developer tools. Does anyone know of any issues in this respect?

M

Comment: Why two HTML markups? Which one is it?

Comment: The first comes from the source view in Chrome, and the second comes from inspecting the checkbox element in Chrome's developer tools.

Comment: why you have hidden field problem is caused by hidden field i susupect

Comment: Ok. so the first one is irrelevant. The important thing is the dev tools as this represents the current state.